# Cannot Set Notification Priority to Low on Android Oreo

Tags: android, notifications

It seems that lowest notification level you can set when creating a Notification Channel on Android Oreo is Medium.

[image: Android Notification Priority]

This is the case even when using `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE`.

```
NotificationChannel sendingChannel = new  NotificationChannel("SENDING", "Sending", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
```

`NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE`, `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN`, and `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW` all set the Notification Channel importance to Medium.

There does not appear to be a way to set the notification importance to low on Android Oreo.

Comment: How are you testing your app? Once you create a channel, the importance level is set forever (even if you delete the channel and recreate it). You have to clear data to reset it completely.

Comment: Complete uninstall and reinstall when testing notifications.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue when trying to set a notification channel to Low for use with a foreground service. I can confirm in that case, the level gets increased to Medium by the system.

See this stack overflow question/answer for details: [Default priority of notification channel on Android 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48704448/default-priority-of-notification-channel-on-android-8?rq=1#)

Documentation for the behavior exists (again, assuming you're using a foreground service) although I would argue it's a bit unclear: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#IMPORTANCE_MIN for details